# Noob file.copy question having issues copying .exe files C#

Tags: c#, file, copy, executable

I am trying to copy a .exe file from the temp directory to the desktop, however when I do so it just creates a new .exe which has no data in it and is 0 KB in size. I tested this syntax with a .txt file and it copied it completely, it just refuses to copy .exe files for some reason. I tried executing it using the the `string path` to make sure it was grabbing the correct location and that worked, executing the helloworld.exe program in the temp directory. Also I do not get any compiler errors, I am on windows 7 x86. Thanks!

```
string path = Path.GetTempPath() + "helloworld.exe"; // grabing the temp directory
string path2 = "C:\\users\\grant\\desktop\\helloworld.exe"; //this is where i want
                                                          //it to copy to
File.Copy(path, path2, true); //copying the 2 paths
Process.Start(path); //running the .exe in the temp directory to test if it works
```

Comment: Don't see why that wouldn't work.  No exceptions thrown?

Comment: Is the exe blocked? Right-click on it...Properties to check. If it has an 'Unblock' button, click that. Also make sure the exe isn't running.

Comment: I am on Windows 7 x86, I am using VC2010 Professional and I am on an Administrator account. The permissions are all checked for Administrator and my current user and the program is unblocked. I checked that the .exe is not running too.

Comment: Try a copy from a non-temp directory or a non .exe file to see it's a more general issue, or just copying a .exe from the temp directory?

Comment: I've tried your code, without any changes except the file path, and it copied the exe fine. Like Joe says, try another exe from another folder.

Comment: Thanks Joe and keyboardP, That worked. It copied it 100%. Does anybody have an idea why a sub directory (desktop\test\helloworld.exe) on my desktop worked instead of the temp folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `.exe` in use during the copy?

Alternatively, any chance AV software is stopping your app making `.exe` copies?

Comment: It is not in use, I am using Avast as my only AV which I just tried disabling it. :(

Comment: Could be the `unblock` bit keyboardP mentioned. He should put that as an answer if it is.

Comment: @Shadowalker An answer is not comprised of 2 questions. What solved the issue for you?

Comment: @TheHurt - OP says the temp folder was the issue. Joe/keyboardP should post an answer and have that accepted instead.

Comment: I think it's only fair if Joe posts as he answered first.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, with File.Copy in C# you need to make sure that the destination file doesn't exist -- File.Copy will fail if you try to copy to an existing file.  So, that could be contributing.

A try/catch block could be handy too:

```
 try 
    {
       string path = Path.GetTempPath() + "helloworld.exe"; 
       string path2 = "C:\\users\\grant\\desktop\\helloworld.exe"; 
       File.Copy(path, path2, true);
    } 

 catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} exception caught.", e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming it before and after copy to a .txt to see if it relates to .exe, even though it seems that something else is wrong in your environement

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it now creates a .txt file with no data at all. Usually when you open a .exe in text format you get gibberish and a header saying this program cannot be run in DOS mode, but I get nothing. Is it just NOT copying it and creating a new file? I am not getting any errors...